# find the nearest number of a 2d list and return as list

Tags: python

I have a 2d list which is a

```
a = [[11, 45], [33, 43], [44, 33], [98, 78]]
b= [23,32]
min(a[0], key=lambda x:abs(x-b[0]))
```

have to find the minimum nearest number in the list
It returned output as 11.
Expected Output should be return as:    [11,45]

Comment: What do you mean by the nearest number, when there are two in each sub-list?

Comment: You have't specified a question about this code, but maybe you are wondering why you are getting a NameError in the last line, telling you `o` isn't defined?

Comment: You might have meant `a[0]`, but then that considers only the first sublist of the list.

Comment: The nearest number to 23 isn't 11, its 33

Comment: I need a output like i mentioned above

Comment: Then you need to explain *why* that is the correct output, because your current explanation shouldn't produce that result. (as @ninesalt points out).

Comment: What happens If you have 2 or more pairs with 11? Which is the min then?

Comment: Above i already mentioned it was 2d List. I have given another one 2d list which is input given by user. so, we have use the 0th column. Based on 0th column of another list we have to find the nearest value

Comment: By what reasoning is 11 closer to 23 than 33 is?

Comment: Also, do you realize that your code ignores all but the first element of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

you should use zero (0) not o

min(a[0], key=lambda x:abs(x-b[0]))

Comment: This does not produce the explicitly stated *desired* result.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to produce the result you describe, in the format you want, even if it doesn't match what you say the answer should be:

```
min( *a, key=lambda x:abs(x[0]-b[0]) )
```

That is, it finds the minimum value from *all* of `a` whose first element is closest to the first element of `b`.